# Email body format changed for some recipients VBA

Tags: vba, excel, email, html-email

I am creating some emails through vba in excel. Currently using the html method for the email body and adding the mail body text by combining values of different cells in a worksheet. I clearly marked the font as Calibri 11 and it is creating the mails with the required font but some users get the mail with different font in email body.

Also, the recipients who are facing this problem have the "Dear" part and "Thank you " part showing as Calibri 11 but the rest of the content in Times New Roman 12. Can someone please help me with this issue.

The code for email body is like this:

```
.htmlbody = "<body style = 'font-size:11pt; font-family:Calibri; color:RGB(0,0,0);'>" & y & vbNewLine & _
                            "<p>" & varPart1 & varPart2 & "<sup>" & varPart3 & "</sup>" & varPart4 & varPart5 & "<sup>" & _
                            varPart6 & "</sup>" & varPart7 & "</p>" & _
                            "<p>" & varPart8 & "</p>" & _
                            "<p><span>" & varPart9 & "</span></p>" & _
                            "<span>" & varPart10 & "</body>"
```

Comment: I see `varPartX` stuff, but no `Dear` or `Thank you` ..we're supposed to assume `varPart1` is the "dear" part and that `varPart10` is the "thank you" part? Also why isn't `RGB(0,0,0)` just not `black`?

Comment: That said, I'd warmly recommend you make a templated string with valid HTML, instead of having this concatenation nightmare with a bunch of meaningless identifiers. Have e.g. `%name%` placeholders in the HTML string, and run a `Replace` on it to replace `%name%` with whatever the final value is.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon the situation demands me to use multiple variables to create the full email.....but i don't understand as to why all the users are receiving the mails in calibri 11 except a few users which are getting some body content as times new roman